# How to search within all textviews inside activity android?

Tags: android

I want to search string entered by user in all content which is currently present in textviews within activity.can You provide the way such that it can be done in minimum time.

Comment: What you have `Tried` show us.

Comment: add your test code

Answer (score 2):

TextView is a View and it just present data from some data source. If user inserted some data, that data has to be "stored" in some data variable and than view should be populated from that data variable. 
In that case, you just search through data variables.

```
int userAge = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText())
...
textView.setText("User age is "+userAge);
```

So, data is in a variable, not in view, and you can compare it, search it, change it.....

Answer (score 1):

```
userTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // search in activity textviews if contain userTextView text
        if (textView1.getText().toString().contains(userTextView.getText()))
            // content found in textView 1
        else if (textView2.getText().toString().contains(userTextView.getText()))
            // content found in textView 2
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```